# Need order and action of pytest hooks execution

Tags: pytest, hook

Can anyone clarify how pytest hooks executes and what it does in each step?

Mainly, could you please tell me why `pytest_plugin_registered` is repeated under `pytest_sessionstart`?. I checked `pytestdebug.log` and it repeats the same plugins' registration.

```
root
└── pytest_cmdline_main
├── pytest_plugin_registered
├── pytest_configure
│ └── pytest_plugin_registered <-------- registers all _pytest plugins, conftest, setup tools plugins
├── pytest_sessionstart
│ ├── pytest_plugin_registered <-------- again registers all same above _pytest plugins, conftest, setup tools plugins
│ └── pytest_report_header
```

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3261#issuecomment-755461808
[image]

Comment: `pytest_plugin_registered` is called after a plugin is registered successfully, it does not register anything. The hook is invoked multiple times because different types of plugins are registered at different time points, but nothing is registered twice as the plugin manager guards that. What is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: Thanks for answer. My question is as per pytestdebug.log (using --debug),  I am seeing two times same plugin is used to call pytest_plugin_registered.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] with the duplicate plugin registration being reproducible and the plugin name visible.

Comment: Added snapshot of pytestdebug.log from actual log. Removed in middle other names to have clear look. If we want to reproduce, we could run "pytest --debug"  option to generate same log.

Comment: Those are two different hooks: one is `TerminalReporter().pytest_plugin_registered()` (invoked during configure phase), the other `FixtureManager().pytest_plugin_registered()` (invoked during session start). Since `pytest_plugin_registered` is a [historic hook](https://pluggy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#historic-hooks), it will trace everything that was registered so far. This doesn't indicate any plugin is registered twice. Are you trying to built some logic based on the trace log? That's internal info anyway. Write your own impl of `pytest_plugin_registered` and use that instead.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling a lot for detailed answers. It would be great if you share some order of  hooks' execution Or table like below. So that end user(like me) will know which hook could be overridden on what purpose.

Comment: |Hook | Action | Override if you want to do |

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227028/discussion-between-mukunthan-ragavan-and-hoefling).

Comment: You will find listing of all hooks that you can implement in [pytest reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#hooks). As for the exact execution order, there's no such reference yet - [#3261](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3261) was opened to address this.